# Как учитывать часовой пояс устройства?

Tags: android

Получаю дни:

```
 new Date.getTime()/86400000
```

Как бы мне скорректировать время по часовому поясу устройства?

Comment: Хм, интересно. Просто я сперва получаю это значение, записываю в переменную. Затем, вот сейчас как стукнуло 00:01 - получил еще одно, тоже деленное (дни). При вычитании одного из другого, судя по коду - ноль. Может накосячил еще где-то... (p.s. мне надо отследить начало нового дня.)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5369682/4279)

Comment: значение `getTime()` (количество миллисекунд с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT`) не зависит от часовой зоны.

Comment: @jfs Благодарю.         Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());  
        today.setToNow();  
        String a = today.format("%k:%M:%S");

Comment: Хотя нет, там говорят что Time устаревает и не рекомендуют его использовать...

Comment: В общем, как я понял - надо использовать GregorianCalendar.

Comment: обновите ваш вопрос и приведите конкретный пример, *что* вы хотите получить. Ещё раз: значение в вопросе не нужно корректировать — оно не меняется какая бы у вас часовая зона не была. Если вы хотите местное время получить, посмотрите в сторону [java.time](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html) (что конкретно использовать, зависит от того что конкретно вы хотите получить).

Comment: Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
А это не подходит?